# On this occasion my class prepared celebration in which I was a host. - articles usage

Tags: articles, sentence-choice

> On this occasion my class prepared celebration in which I was a host.
>
> On this occasion my class prepared **the** celebration in which I was a
>   host.
>
> On this occasion my class prepared **a** celebration in which I was a
>   host.

Which article should I choose and why? Maybe none

Comment: To use *articles* correctly, it needs a context. If your listener knows which celebration you are preparing, then **the** is can be used.

Comment: **for** which? "On this occasion my class prepared a celebration for which I was (a) host.  .You only need the **a** if there are multiple hosts.

Answer (score 1):

The choice that sounds natural to me is the 3rd.

```
On this occasion my class prepared a celebration in which I was a host.
```

Because "celebration" needs an article. so the first choice is out. It cannot be preceded by "the" unless it's mentioned in a previous sentence. So the 3rd usage sounds more natural given the context available.

Also I would like to weigh in on the discussion about Celebration vs party: I would substitute "celebration" with "function".

Merriam-Webster  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/function

```
4 an official or formal ceremony or social gathering 
  <They went to several functions during their college reunion weekend.>
```

Final comment is why not

```
 "of" which I was a host.
```

Answer (score 0):

The third option sounds the most natural.

"The celebration" sounds a little awkward but I can't describe why.

Having no article is definitely out. You'll usually see an article when a noun is in this kind of position. But not always. "Prepare a humburger" versus "preparing dinner". I'm not sure what the pattern is there.

Also, calling it a celebration sounds a little formal, you might consider using a word like "party"

Comment: I wanted to replace a school jubilee with something and I thought about "celebration". Would you recommend something else because it seems to me that "paty" would be inappropriate. It's about the fifteenth anniversary of school and it's about celebrating it? Would it be "ceremony" or "academy"?

Comment: Yeah, maybe "party" is too casual for kind of situation